# A Calculus book that doesn't have a Gazillion pages?

Tags: calculus, reference-request

Okay, so I have mastered high-school level Calculus (A-Level calculus, to be exact) and am now looking to self-study some university level Calculus and Differential Equations so that I can move on to learning Classical Mechanics and Quantum Mechanics. I need a book as a supplement to the Calculus course at the MIT OpenCourseWare site. MIT suggests Calculus with Analytical Geometry, but that book has about 1200 pages.

I have ordinary final year high-school stuff to do too, so I only have limited time (like an hour a day) to self-learn university Calculus. Is there a somewhat more compact book that doesn't cut out the essential stuff but will get me done with the course quicker?

Comment: There's Spivak's Calculus which is about half the length. Maybe you should try it out.

Comment: You might consider Lang's Short Calculus. It doesn't do epsilon-delta proofs, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @DylonChow nice, only 260 pages. Does it cover most of the essential stuff, though? To prepare me for Classical and Quantum mechanics?

Comment: I don't know what you'd need for classical and quantum mechanics, unfortunately... I know that it does not have multivariable calculus or differential equations.